# Cloud Storage, uploading from string encoding

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use the `python` client to upload a string to a blob.

When I am printing the string in my console - all is well, when uploaded to the bucket it is full of strange encodings errors, such as:

`I am bitterly disappointed â€“Â he should take the right to vote very seriously.`

Here is my code:

```py
from datetime import date
from google.cloud import storage

URL_TEXT_BUCKET = 'BUCKET-NAME'

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(URL_TEXT_BUCKET)

def store_url_content(text, key):
    today = str(date.today())
    blob = bucket.blob(today + '/' + key)
    blob.upload_from_string(text)
```

I have tried setting `encoding_type='utf8'`, but with no luck the docs do not state the options or best practices.

EDIT:
I have also tried to encode my text as `utf8`, by calling:

`text = text.encode('utf8')`

Whilst this made a change in the viewer and seemed to replace some elements with what I believe to be `bytes` and also prepending a `b`  `b'some text x\u023 more'` - the final result on GCS was the same.

EDIT 2:
The issue is with the Google Console viewer, downloading the file back displays all fine...

Would be great if someone with knowledge about the GCP console could help fix why the text is not being rendered correctly.

Comment: Python version? The text you are trying to upload is not shown This is an encoding problem either on upload or in your viewer.

Comment: I am using python 3, how would I check? Adding some more details on text.

Comment: You’ll need to provide even more details. When you call `Blob.upload_from_string`, the first arg can be bytes or a Python 3 string (which is what in Python 2 was a Unicode string). In case of the latter, it will be automatically encoded using UTF-8. It sounds to me like the viewer you are using doesn't decode the bytes using the appropriate encoding. Which viewer are you using? Are you uploading bytes (if so, which encoding did you use) or unicode strings?

Comment: @OliverW. I am uploading a string. When you say viewer - do you mean of the file once uploaded? I am just using the GCP console.

Comment: The viewer is the program you use to display the file. I don't have access to a GCP console, so I can’t check which encoding it uses. If you download the file again, and view it in different programs (or reload it in Python), does it still display the “funny” characters?

Comment: Thanks @OliverW. you are correct - the issue is with the viewer, do you know anyway to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem with C#. 
When uploading html files most of the special characters from the keyboard are shown with this encoding problem. 
If I download and open again the offline file on the browser it shows the correct symbols.
At Google Cloud documentation is said the default encoding is uf-8 instead. No idea why.